# Return Value inside if statement inside for loop inside function

Tags: php, for-loop, if-statement, return, return-value

My goal in the below code is to cycle through the IF statement and have the function return a True value if the IF statement holds true throughout all the iterations?  If during any iteration the evaluation is false I want to immediately return False. Am I writing this correctly?  I get confused with the order of operations within the IF statement.  Is there a simpler more elegant way to write this?

```
function checkGroup($groupNum, $names, $namesNow, $$group, $groupSize, $i){
  for ($m=0; $m < count($$group); ++$m){
    //checks to make sure current person doesn't conflict with anyone else in current group
    if ($namesNow[$names[$i]][$$group[$m]] < $max ){
      continue;
    }
    else {
      return false;
      break;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Why would you need variable variable?  I mean $$group.

Comment: Double $ must be a typo when copying code to SO, as it's invalid in this context.

Comment: $$group is a variable variable. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php   the code for that is below.  it helps me create arrays named group1, group2, etc.  $groupNum = 1;
  $group = "group".$groupNum;
  $$group = array();

Answer (score 1):

why not you try like this, revert the if condition

```
function checkGroup($groupNum, $names, $namesNow, $$group, $groupSize, $i){
   for ($m=0; $m < count($$group); ++$m){
   //checks to make sure current person doesn't conflict with anyone else in current group
      if ($namesNow[$names[$i]][$$group[$m]] >= $max ){
         return false;
      }
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: No need for `break` after returning, though.

Comment: Thanks - i like that .  i think you're right in that it is a little more strightforward

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do something like this

```php
function checkGroup($groupNum, $names, $namesNow, $group, $groupSize, $i){
    $ret = true;
    for ($m=0; $m < count($group); ++$m /* or $m++? */){
        //checks to make sure current person doesn't conflict with anyone else in current group
        if (!($namesNow[$names[$i]][$group[$m]] < $max)){
            $ret = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about something like that.  i like it